# The irreducible representations of a $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, representation-theory, p-groups

If $P$ is a group of order $p$ and $K$ is a field of characteristic $p$, then how can I show that the trivial representation is the only irreducible representation of $P$?  I have a feeling that I should be using eigenvalues somewhere, but am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: The minimal polynomial of an element of $P$ in its action on a vector space is $(x^{p^k}-1) = (x-1)^{p^k}$ for some $k \ge 0$, so $1$ is an eigenvalue, and the representation has a fixed point.

Comment: @DerekHolt Answers should be answers, not comments.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy My comment is not a complete answer, it is just a suggestion of one method of approaching the problem. Also (as far as I know) comments can be deleted if they turn out to be misguided, but answers remain there for the rest of eternity.